# UX for RESTful UIButton actions

Tags: ios, rest, uibutton, user-experience

A UIButton triggers its action restfully (i.e., through a GET, POST, or PUT request). Should the action be encapsulated in such a way that the beginning disables the button, while the end enables it again?

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    self.button.enabled = NO;

    ... RESTful API . . . 

    self.button.enabled = YES;


}
```

What is the best UX for button actions in iOS?

Comment: yes, but the enabling of the button would happen in some callback and not directly in the `buttonTapped` function (either via completion block or delegate method) probably should show a loading indicator somewhere as well. but this kind of question isnt quite the type of question to be asking on SO, because it doesnt really have a definitive answer (as with most UX questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you need to prevent to call a REST API function twice or more and the approach to disable button is feasible/appreciated. 
Don't forget to use sort of activity indicator to follow Apple rules.

EDIT: It really depends on your implementation, I use in this case AFNetworking library to handle REST API call and then build functions with asynchronous calls, when a call is OK or failure just release the button to be active again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think so too but I do not know what is the best way. Do you know what might be the best way or the different scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Button tap will be performed on the main thread, so implementing synchronous call will create you a lot of problems. Do implement delegate methods(you class should conform to a protocol) or callbacks depending on your networking client API.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    self.button.enabled = NO;
    ...
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
...
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    ...
    self.button.enabled = YES;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ...
    self.button.enabled = YES;
}
```

Examples

1. NSURLConnection http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example
2. AFNetworking http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial